# Обозначение звука

Tags: фонетика

Что это обозначает - а1? Вот тут в табличке, например, он

[Адъективное Склонение | rusgram.narod.ru](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1294-1314.html#1310)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что это обозначает - а1?

См. [**§ 131:**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/116-135.html#131)

> § 131… |a1| - слабая фонема второго, третьего предударных и заударных
>   слогов после твердых и мягких согласных… реализуется в двух вариантах:
>   [ъ] - после твердых, [ь] - после мягких.